# Invoking an Obj-C class method named `init` from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm using a 3rd party library in my Swift 4.1 code that has an Obj-C header file with a class level method named `init()`.  When I try to invoke it, the compiler gets confused and says it's ambiguous whether I want to use an instance initializer or this static init method, like so:

`My3rdPartyClass.init() // Error: Ambiguous use of 'init()'`

In the `My3rdPartyClass.h` file:

```
@interface My3rdPartyClass : NSObject

+(void)init;

@end
```

Comment: “that has an Obj-C header file with a class level method named init()” Okay, well, that’s illegal. You cannot call that method from Swift; you will have to write a trampoline in Objective-C. (Assuming you cannot change the source code.) And please excoriate the developer of this library.

Comment: And in Swift 4.2 you should be able to say `My3rdPartyClass.\`init\`()` in order to tell Swift "yes, I mean an identifier" (IIRC, Swift 4.2 is the first version to properly differentiate initialisers from static members named `init`, so this won't work in 4.1). But yeah, this is a bad API.

Comment: @Hamish: Indeed, I had not noticed that. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @MartinR I'm happy if you want to include it in your answer – otherwise I fear I would duplicate most/all of the points already made by your excellent answer (and as OP says they're using 4.1, a 4.2 only solution doesn't feel like a direct answer).

Comment: @Hamish: Does that “backtick trick” work for factory initialisers as well? I could not figure out how to apply it at https://stackoverflow.com/q/53704499/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR I don't believe so, as factory methods are imported as initialisers rather than static members named `init`. The behaviour OP is getting in that Q&A is a bug at any rate though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ambiguity arises (in **Swift <= 4.1**) because both the class method

```
+ (void)init;
```

and `NSObject`s init method

```
- (instancetype)init
```

are called from  Swift as `My3rdPartyClass.init()`. Possible solutions
are:

- Rename the Objective-C class method.
- Annotate the function declaration with a different Swift name:

  ```
  +(void)init NS_SWIFT_NAME(classInit());
  ```

  That leaves the Objective-C interface unchanged, but the function can
  be called from Swift as

  ```
  OClass.classInit()
  ```
- If no modification of the Objective-C header file is possible then
  you can still call the function from Swift as

  ```
  My3rdPartyClass.init() as Void
  ```

  The `Void` return type resolves the ambiguity.

Starting with **Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10)** you can call the class method as

```
OClass.`init`()
```

without any changes in the Objective-C API (attribution goes to
@Hamish).  The backticks tell the compiler that you mean the
member function, not the initializer.