# ObjC <-> Swift bridging and factory methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've some Objective-C class that I want to use from Swift.
For reasons that are beyond the scope of this question, my class `init` method is marked as unavailable. Instead, there is a factory method. This is a simplification of how my class looks like:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
+ (instancetype)myClass;
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
@end
```

When I use it from Swift, I can do `let x = MyClass()` and this is fine because, according to the bridging rules, the compiler tries to map factory methods to normal initializers. The problem is that the "unavailable" `init` method is invoked instead of the factory method.

How do I make Swift use the factory method?

---

**Additional experiments:**

I'm sure `NS_UNAVAILABLE` works, because if I do:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
@end
```

Then on the Swift side, I get the expected `'init()' is unavailable` error message.

This means that it is the factory method that allows `let x = MyClass()` to compile, but at runtime the "wrong" method is called.

Comment: Looks like a bug in these tools. If I were I'd just rename the factory method to anything else and use it in Swift like `MyClass.instance()`

Comment: Yes sure, I can do that, but I'd prefer to allow the standard `_ = MyClass()` from Swift if possible. 

Another solution is to call the factory method from the init, but that means (besides being a code smell) that 2 allocations are done.

Comment: It seems like a compiler bug and I'll report it, I just wanted to know if someone else encountered it and managed to solve it :)

Comment: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that swapping the two methods in the header file, namely

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
+ (instancetype)myClass;
@end
```

does the trick. Thanks to Hamish Knight who found it (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9456).

I'll go with this approach until this is properly fixed on the compiler side.